# Gradient Methods with Errors

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Consider $f$ a $C^1$ function. Let $\{x^k\}$ be a sequence such that

$$d^k = f'(x^k) + \epsilon^k, \quad \Vert \epsilon^k \Vert \leq \delta;$$
$$x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha_k d^k.$$

Show that for every $\delta'> \delta$ there exist $\overline{\alpha} \geq \underline{\alpha} > 0$ such that if $\alpha_k \in [\underline{\alpha}, \overline{\alpha}]$ then $\{x^k\}$ admits a accumulation point $\overline{x}$ such that $\Vert f'(\overline{x}) \Vert \leq \delta'$.

I could only show this using that $f$ is a Lipschitz function. This problem can be found In Bersetkas's book on [nonlinear programing](https://www.amazon.com.br/Nonlinear-Programming-Dimitri-P-Bertsekas/dp/1886529051) and there is a solution in Bersetka's site. However, he also assume that $f$ is Lipschitz. My question is: Is this hypothesis necessary?

Comment: The assumption that $f$ has a Lipschitz gradient (the gradient, not the function) is required in order to provide sufficient decrease in each step. If you remove that assumption then you cannot use a fixed step size anymore (regardless of the $\epsilon$-error). Then by using a different line search strategy you might still be able to prove the desired result, which is an accumulation point in which $\|\nabla f(\bar{x})\|\leq \delta'$, however it will be more complex to analyze. Try doing so using the Armijo Rule

Comment: Could you elaborate more what happens if you remove the assumption?

Comment: My gut feels like we could perhaps get away with some sort of locally-Lipschitz property if your initial iterate is "close enough" to a solution. But that's more of a hypothesis trade-off than an improvement